# Can I consistently clone chickens?

Tags: slime-rancher

After unlocking access to Viktor's Workshop and its Slimeulations, one of the first rewards from successfully catching Glitch Slimes and submitting their bug reports is the so-called Chicken Cloner, which promises to "Double your chickens, half of the time". The other half, the chicken is simply vaporized with no trace.

Now, mathematically speaking, if each chicken has a 1/2 chance of being destroyed, and a 1/2 chance of producing another chicken, then the expected number chickens from each cloning attempt is... 1. No gain, no loss. Can I improve my chances and clone more chickens consistently, somehow?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lot of chickens, you can attempt to clone a single chicken, if it dissapears, put twice as many chickens inside the cloner.

This only fails when you no longer have enough chickens to double the amount, hence giving you good odds of getting one chicken and very small odds of losing a whole lot of chickens.
The wiki mentions no way to increase the odds.

Comment: This is a good strategy if I'm trying to get one more chicken and I already have a large amount of chickens (in which case, why am I trying so hard to get one more chicken?). I was more wondering if there's a way to consistently expect, say, 1.2 chickens for each cloning attempt, which would make the cloner at least profitable.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that you can only clone one chicken at a time, so the idea of "double your bets until you win" isn't as straightforward.

Comment: sounds like the cloner is essentially a novelty, unless you can abuse save/load (save before cloning chickens, loading when you are out of chickens) the cloner seems to have little to no practical purpose.

Comment: This answer describes the [Martingale System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28betting_system%29). It does not work. All it does is take a game which promises an equal chance for an equal win or loss into a game with a large chance for a tiny win vs. a tiny chance for a catastrophic loss (when you run out of chicken to double).